# How to delete installer.exe file from desktop?

Tags: installation

I have an installer.exe file on my desktop and it doesn't allowed me to delete that file. Error i face is "Couldn't find installer.exe" I have tried all possible ways like anti-virus scan, cmd DEL command but it is not removing from my desktop, i also searched everywhere but i am not getting expected answer. i've also posted picture of error i am facing So,Is anyone know how should i remove that file from my desktop?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simple answer to solve this.
right click on installer.exe from desktop and select add to archieve.
and then  while creating archieve there will b an option at rightside delete file aftr archieving. done
 :) thank me later

Answer (score 1):

with a bootable live cd like ubuntu or Kali Linux you will be able to delete every file you want in your windows file system

Comment: i don't know how to use linux so is there any other way?

Comment: at boot time of your system try to enter safe mode, may be you will have a chance but not sure if it's some kind of a virus... (usually by F8 at boot)

Comment: another way, you can try a bootable windows system called ERD for windows 7 or 8 or what you have as an os if available for it

Answer (score 0):

If this file is in any folder and you have not other important contents in that folder then try to delete that folder using command prompt.

Steps:

```
1. Go to Command prompt with administrative privilege.
2. Go to your installer.exe file path by cd Path
3. Get out from that folder by cd..
4. type rm /S folderName and press enter
5. When asking to delete file say Yes by pressing Y
```

You are done.Be happy!